# Logstash log parsing

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I've got this log message:

```
Jul 23 09:24:16 mmr mmr-core[5147]:  Aweg3AOMTs_1563866656876839.mt GetProvider_v4
```

which I ship to the elasticsearch.

I'd like to parse it in logstash filter and make id field from Aweg3AOMTs_1563866656876839.mt except I don't want to involve either letter or other characters and have in the id only the number!

I've done so far:

```
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:logtimestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} %{DATA:type} %{USERNAME:id} %{GREEDYDATA:rest}

  "logtimestamp": "Jul 23 09:24:16",
  "hostname": "mmr",
  "id": "Aweg3AOMTs_1563866656876839.mt",
  "type": "mmr-core[5147]:"
```

How can I skip the letters and characters in the id field?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What are the possible formats that this id can be in? Can you be sure that all the numbers will be in a row without any other characters between them?

Comment: @mihomir it's only format the id can be in :)) All numbers are in a row without characters between !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want just the `1563866656876839` in your `id` field? You could divide the `Aweg3AOMTs_1563866656876839.mt` string into three fields: `id_prefix`, `id` and `id_suffix` and then [remove](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_field) the parts that you don't need.

Pattern to try in the [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/):

```
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:logtimestamp}\s%{HOSTNAME:hostname}\s%{DATA:type}\s%{USERNAME:id_prefix}_%{NUMBER:id}\.%{GREEDYDATA:id_suffix}\s%{GREEDYDATA:rest}
```

Logstash config:

```
# logstash.conf
…
filter {
    grok {
        match => {
            "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:logtimestamp}\s%{HOSTNAME:hostname}\s%{DATA:type}\s%{USERNAME:id_prefix}_%{NUMBER:id}\.%{GREEDYDATA:id_suffix}\s%{GREEDYDATA:rest}"
        }
    }
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["id_prefix", "id_suffix"]
    }
}
…
```